# Reference cell values in Json.Document() - EXCEL Data sources

Tags: excel, powerquery

I used the From Web function in EXCEL to load a a JSON document from the Web.

If I then Show Query, EXCEL has generated this call:

Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://blah.com/stuff"))

I'd like to edit that so rather than hard coding "http://blah.com/stuff" I'd like to pull the address from a cell in a WorkSheet.

Can anyone help me with what to put here?

Json.Document(Web.Contents(<<>>))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the spreadsheet cell with your URL a Name (using Name Manager) eg MyUrl

Insert a line above your Json.Document call (don't forget the comma at the end)

`JsonURL = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyUrl"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],`

Then amend the next line to:
`Json.Document(Web.Contents(JsonURL))`